# What Won't this Query Run Without Restarting MySQL

Tags: mysql

This query dies, unless I restart MySQL just before it.  If just run it, it times out, but if I restart then run it, it completes in less than a  seconds.

```
select  
u.id as wp_id,
(select user_id from htts_private_003.Purchasers_wp_phpbb3 where id=u.id and       user_id      is not null order by user_id desc limit 1) as user_id, 
count(*)
FROM   
`auto-19414-1`.`wp_users` u 
left join htts_private_003.User_accounts_wp_bb ui on u.id =ui.wp_id
where ui.wp_id is  null
and (select user_id from htts_private_003.Purchasers_wp_phpbb3 where id=u.id and     user_id  is not null order by user_id desc limit 1) is not null
group by (select user_id 
from htts_private_003.Purchasers_wp_phpbb3 where id=u.id     order by user_id desc limit 1)
having count(*) = 1
```

How do I figure out the problem and solve it?   Nothing I put into Google brings back anything explaining this, I am hoping someone here can help

There are indexes on all the fields involved.  It is as if the indexes are gone and a restart brings them back.  I don't know of indexes created on restart... so I am stuck.

EXPLAIN
Here is what came back when using EXPLAIN with MySQL for this query:
[image: image of the EXPLAIN results]

Comment: please post the `EXPLAIN` of the query as well as some overall details about your database memory/storage ----- Also what other queries are you running before this one?

Comment: John, I posted the EXPLAIN results in the main question, to respond to your request.  Regarding the queries before this one, there is a series reading tables from an online forum, each dropping and creating tables with their results.  Sum of rows in all the tables is about 200k.  The server has 1G of ram with dedicated dual core processor.    The purpose of this query is to find unique forum members from a list containing multiple accounts for a lot of members.  If there is anything else you need to know, please ask.  Thank you for responding.